# Java environment variables under Windows 2012R2

Tags: java, tomcat

We are trying to run Apache-Tomcat which would start / stop as a service. However, when trying to set it up, we get error messages as for unset variables, making it impossible to set it as a service. Looking at the file, and given that this is a .BAT file, as provided by the distribution, is there an easy way to set the JAVA-HOME and other required variables for Java to be set globally for the box ? Our main challenge is to get Apache-Tomcat copied / setup through a script, and the environment variables globally (and permanently) set so that when the server is rebooted, or the service started/stopped/restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is only used when running the `service.bat` file. Once the service has been created, it has embedded the value, so changing a global `JAVA_HOME` environment variable will make no difference.

When you want to use a different `JAVA_HOME` value, you have to deregister the service and reregister with the new value.

This is regardless of Windows version. Also remember to run `service.bat` "as admin".

---

There is a good reason why a registered Tomcat instance is not using global environment values. As an example, we're running 6 different Tomcat instances on our UAT server, each with a different combination of Tomcat version and Java version. We couldn't do that if all the instances were using a single global `JAVA_HOME` or `CATALINA_HOME` value.